# How do I get the NSMutableString of data and place it in different string?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a method that contains data. I want to create a string of that data and write it to a text file. I have created a write to text method. How do I get the NSMutableString of data in UpLoadDeviceData method to my writetotext method's string* contents? Here is the method where the data is being pulled:

Here is my write to text method:

```
-(void) writeToTextFile{

    //get mydocuments dir
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // System's date and timestamp
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date]; 
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM.dd.YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
    // NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "string that data" when your data is already a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an non-mutable string from the mutable string and write to file:

```
NSMutableString *theMutableString; 
NSString *nonMutableString = [NSString stringWithString:theMutableString]; 
[nonMutableString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:nil];
```

Or, shorter, write the mutable string to file:

```
[theMutableString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:nil]; +
```

Some words about how to construct longer strings:

- If you want to append a string to a mutable string, use `appendString:`.
- The much less efficient way is to use the `NSString` class method `stringByAppendingString:`. That allocates a new string and creates unnecessary overhead.
- Your preferred method, using then `NSString` class method `stringWithFormat:` is even worse because now there is additional effort necessary to scan a format string.

Therefore: the best way is to construct your mutable string piece by piece and then write it to file in a one-liner.

Comment: Isn't json already a string? Just make it an ivar and you have access to it anywhere.

Comment: See my answer: `appendString`.